# MUI Autocomplete custom options, not showing selected option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI v5 `Autocomplete` for my dropdown.

I have options with `title` and `id` when an option is selected, I want to store the `id` in the state, also want to update the select (autocomplete here) value with selected movie.

The textbox in the select is not reflecting the value set using `value` props.

I tried `isOptionEqualToValue` but it helps to highlight the value when the dropdown is open. When drop-down is closed, the selected movie name is not reflected.

https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-osex0?file=/demo.js

```js
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = React.useState(2);

  return (
    <>
      Movie ID value in the state {movie}
      <Autocomplete
        disablePortal
        id="combo-box-demo"
        value={movie == null ? "" : movie}
        options={top100Films}
        onChange={(e, data) => {
          if (data && data.id) {
            setMovie(data.id);
          }
        }}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title || ""}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value}
      />
    </>
  );
}

const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", id: 1 },
  { title: "The Godfather", id: 2 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", id: 3 }
];
```

Even when the option is selected, it is not reflecting in the textbox

[image: Even when the option is selected, it is not reflecting in the textbox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` prop should be one of the object in the `options` array if you want to use the [controlled mode](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#playground):

```
const getDefaultOption = () => top100Films.find((m) => m.id === 2) ?? null;

export default function ComboBox() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = React.useState(getDefaultOption);

  return (
    <>
      <Box mb={3}>Movie ID value in the state {movie.id}</Box>
      <Autocomplete
        disablePortal
        id="combo-box-demo"
        value={movie}
        options={top100Films}
        onChange={(e, data) => setMovie(data)}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title || ""}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: What if you want the "unselected" state but still have a controlled component?